# Can I use a nullable float (float?) in WaitForSeconds()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have a default "unhurt" time for my platformer where my player transitions from a hurt state to normal; The normal time I think is .54 seconds. However for specific objects I want the unhurt time to be shorter. I did this by adding this to my unhurt IEnumerator

```
 IEnumerator Unhurt(float? time2)
    {
        time2 = 4;
        SoundMan1.PlayHurtSound();
      //  SoundMan1.PlayerHurt3.PlayOneShot(SoundMan1.PlayrHurtClips3[Random.Range(0, 3)]);
        Debug.Log("Unhurting!");
        if(time2 == null)
        {
            

        } if(time2 > .02f && time2!=null)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(time2);
        }
        else
        {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(unhurttime);
        }
        IsHurt = false;
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
        Debug.Log("Unhurt");
    }
```

And In my spike script (the script I'm calling this coroutine from.) This is the code calling it..

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().StartCoroutine("Unhurt");
```

I want it so that if I don't write anything after the  "Unhurt" then the time2 float? will be null and it'll just wait the default duration. The problem is the WaitForSeconds(time2); has an error. It says cannot convert float? to float.

If I add a .2f or whatever after the "Unhurt" and pass that in as time2, I want the float to not be null and then it'll wait that new duration.

Comment: You should use `time2.HasValue` to check if it has a value and `time2.Value` for the value once you're certain it has one. Since you assign it a value on the first line of the function it will always have a value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you can not!

As the error tells you `WaitForSeconds` expects a `float`.

You are passing in a `float?` which is just a synonym for [`Nullable<float>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) which is a completely different type.

---

What you want is the [`time2.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value). Before accessing it you should rather check for [`time2.HasValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.hasvalue) instead of `== null` (internally the `==` uses the `HasValue` anyway and thus is only more expensive).

---

Now in your code there are a lot of open questions though.

Why on the top of the method the first thing you do is overwrite

```
time2 = 4;
```

no matter what, so you totally ignore whatever value is passed in? I guess you would only want to do that in case no value has been passed in.

Then later you check

```
if(time2 > .02f && time2!=null)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time2);
}
```

so before you even check whether it has a value you already want to compare it to `0.02`. Without the assigning mentioned above you should rather check in the order

```
if(time2.HasValue && time2.Value > 0.02f)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time2.Value);
}
```

---

> I want it so that if I don't write anything after the "Unhurt" then the time2 float? will be null

What you are speaking about is called an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) and requires you to actually assign a default value and would rather look like e.g.

```
IEnumerator Unhurt(float? time2 = null)
```

**However** you don't need any nullable for this. Why not simply give it a default value and not use a nullable at all like

```
IEnumerator Unhurt(float time2 = 4f)
```

this time if you don't pass in any value explicitly it will always have the default value `4`.

---

Finally in general to make you live way easier **don't** use the stringed version of `StartCoroutine`!

Rather have a method like

```
public void StartUnhurt(float time2 = 4f)
{
    StartCoroutine (Unhurt(time2));
}
```

and use it like

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().StartUnhurt();
```

or

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().StartUnhurt(3.5f);
```